AWS Auto Scaling Group Stuck in 'Updating Capacity' During Scale-In
I’m using ECS Managed Auto Scaling with Target Tracking.
When the Target Tracking service performs a scale-out action, everything works as expected: the Auto Scaling Group (ASG) launches new instances to accommodate the increased demand.
However, when the Target Tracking service performs a scale-in action, the following issues occur:

Tasks are stopped as expected.
The Auto Scaling Group gets stuck in the "Updating capacity" state.
The extra instances are not terminated, resulting in unused instances being left active.

This behavior seems inconsistent with the expected functionality, where the ASG should terminate unused instances during a scale-in event.
CloudWatch metrics show that the Target Tracking policy is triggering correctly.
Could you help me to figure out the following:

What could cause the Auto Scaling Group to remain stuck in the "Updating capacity" state during a scale-in event?
Are there additional configurations steps I should check to ensure the ASG properly terminates instances?


So, guys, the issue was caused by the absence of this tag in the Auto Scaling Group configuration:
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "test" {
  # ... other configuration, including potentially other tags ...

  tag {
    key                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
    value               = true
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}

